# Npm Test Firebase Error

Tags: unit-testing, firebase, circleci

I am trying to run some tests on my code. But every time that I try to run them this is what is returned

```
> stockmarketsimulator@0.0.0 test /home/ubuntu/workspace
 > mocha


home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/cjs/src       /firebaseApp.js:343
throw appErrors.create(code, args);
^
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
at error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/cjs/src/firebaseApp.js:343:21)
at app (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/cjs/src/firebaseApp.js:227:13)
at Object.serviceNamespace [as database] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/cjs/src/firebaseApp.js:283:47)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/news.js:7:25)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/test.js:8:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
at Array.forEach (native)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
at Mocha.run (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:514:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:484:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

But when I preview the app on heroku, the app works fine.

test.js

```
this.jsdom = require('jsdom-global')()
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');

 var expect = require("chai").expect;
 var test = require("../public/javascripts/testing");
 var getStock = require("../public/javascripts/getStock.js");
 var index = require("../routes/index.js");
var news = require("../routes/news.js");
var express = require('express');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var router = express.Router();
var yahooStocks = require("yahoo-stocks");


before(function(done) {
var config = {
    apiKey: process.env.firebase,
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("default", "default");

done();
})


describe("Home page tests", function() {

it("Should Callback AAPL",function(done) {
    this.timeout(3000);
    news.get_stock_news("AAPL",function(data){
        console.log(data);
        expect(data).to.be.above(0);
        done();
    })
 })
 });
```

news.js

```
var express = require('express');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var router = express.Router();
var https = require("https");

// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
var googleFinance = require('google-finance');
var userUid;
var handle;
var signedIn = false;
var  names = [];
var info = [];
var urls = [];
var namesReturned = [];

var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' +         password).toString('base64');

   function get_stock_news(symbol,callback){
          var request = https.request({
            method: "GET",
            host: "api.intrinio.com",
            path:"/news?ticker="+symbol+"&page_size=1",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": auth
            }
            } , function(response) {
                  var json = "";
                  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                      json += chunk;
                  });
                  response.on('end', function() {
                      var company = JSON.parse(json);
                      callback(company.data[0].ticker);

                  });
                });

 });

 module.exports = router;
 module.exports.get_stock_news = get_stock_news;
```

above is the code that I am using. The code works, so if there is some missing semi colons or something, its from my formatting. The issue is when I try to run some tests that I get the error that the firebase has not been initiliazed

Comment: Please share you code and tests that aren't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `var database = firebase.database();` in `news.js` before you call `firebase.initializeApp()` in `test.js`.

It looks like you are not using `database`, so remove line 7 in `news.js` and try it. If you need it for other tests (that you did not include above), initialize `database.js` in `test.js` and pass it in as a dependency to your `news.get_stock_news` function or add a `initDatabase(firebaseApp)` function in your `news.js` and call it before each test to properly setup the `database`.